# how to code if statement when using a sensor

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors

i have a temperature and humidity code i want to add "if temperature is less than 5 degrees display 40 on lcd screen. How do i do this.

```
    #include "DHT.h"
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

    #define DHTPIN 22     // what pin we're connected to

    #define DHTTYPE DHT11   

    DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
    LiquidCrystal lcd(8,9,4,5,6,7); 

    void setup(void) {
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.print("Reading sensor");
    dht.begin();
        }

    void loop() {

    float temperature, humidity;

    humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    temperature = dht.readTemperature();
    delay(2000); 

    lcd.clear();

    char tempF[6]; 
    char humF[6];
    dtostrf(temperature, 5, 1, tempF);
    dtostrf(humidity, 2, 0, humF);

    lcd.print("T:"); 
    lcd.print(tempF);
    lcd.print((char)223);
    lcd.print("C ");
    lcd.print("H: ");
    lcd.print(humF);
    lcd.print("%");
    }
```

this is my code so far

Comment: That looks like C, not Java. Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Arduino is C++ not Java. However the syntax is the same basically, if(temperature < 5){ //do this display}else{//do this otherthing}

Comment: Did you read at least one C or C++ book before starting coding? If so, did you read the chapter on conditional statements (aka IF)?

Answer (score 0):

Right here, in your code

```
    float temperature, humidity;

    humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    temperature = dht.readTemperature();
    delay(2000);
```

add the condition

```
    float temperature, humidity;

    humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    temperature = dht.readTemperature();

    temperature = (temperature < 5)?40:temperature;

    delay(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more begineer friendly method of doing this:

```
float temperature, humidity;

humidity = dht.readHumidity();
temperature = dht.readTemperature();

  if(temperature < 5)
  {
    //code to display 40 on lcd screen
  }

delay(2000);
```